# Drupal 7 site display unexpected symbols

Tags: 7, ssl

My site working very effectively on my localhost, but when I move the working site's all folders and files to Live Server i.e to cPanel, Its only display unexpected symbols that are given below.

```
‹Ý0M™å‘/ðë¥R!ŒH6L¨½¯Tl³/)4-/`4A‹.iÌ$³·†1‚š–b·Ê¹¢jZ-"¯i!¶=Ç¡Wô¶Ö¢c.kžu›pW:W_R–ÚF½¶™Õj!jWÒj5ƒ°µöÃb‚¹hB:=ú…4Íçÿ Ÿ>ÿ’ubK-NeýS¥#™Ú÷<‘FªR%•ûöËÝÍÍ—õm{£òùÅ<CR€u"Ôµ±/”hŒJ¨w}F{¼”Zï¦‘‡oýùZ,Oä¿G{ð&i:¯y`ðŠkë#o¥ F`xMû&©Lh¥26ˆÊaäÁ(•¤l¬æ š×+8]r¯Bš%êðÐ¸¢Zœ%<_I6Ðq¤*dÏÔ¡zssSyAþƒT²É¶iDƒ¡âž™r t%K,¡¨²,i©LLùzxI{¨å‘ÀŸêŸG°²ƒ#ˆÔ    ¬Ë$KÔk¾„­÷À;ÈB;ß^¬gå‘%éZÀ£kÒOX·™sß—“fêIùk—†<6©{[õzuÃüçà5¸W} µ—Em«(½‚öWEm·^¯„ÍŠv²Ï˜ªS6“„*°iY2qh·HÈ|NÁõÕúG§¤HšëÖHñµ’):à­R âÈ¡–}j.•¬†E»êv×µ@1G³”Êb“–ÈêÂ¶N€Ê]™’q'”±P‹ØM¹ø‘¦1Ãº‰+n;Øûxm%ø}ð0úG,_VŒ6q;zVLsÌ½k–Ô6j¯1ç]Îß`5å•pˆl›Â½ÆkàUÏÜ'¬00Ø½~öY‰¬©Ëœ”“z´XRVŽ6?õÊÅ•“€È&aEaµè!Î‹c¹}ËìóˆÉL%j[®HÓ]Htd¦ôÜ®/wI†,qÖ¥i F®*kèèþÕøDqºÙW3ß`þ©êˆ.Úw=Y.½fž2ëÌKZÖñ¦GÉ<Ÿˆ9$Ø¡pù#gk> W%!:Žçèt©#ÆÔ"ƒƒU~–¸’¿šµ­ÚVù<±"ä"òXNas•øý$i€¨3Õ¬·>i¦_Õ6WÅõrQËªåQ‡C%œÙyÙ)…lÒòºmŽ™OÅÉ”s¼•Ÿ“ìý|ò÷ÑC'ÔÚwùõ'Ygçô8Ú<áZ›í_¯ò´J- .xwø„*¾‹…œ€õ‘â;°`Ð|Ê£íí» ‡ƒþmÛql»ÕøñÓÁáþåþ'ÇiaãÚÕ_õ´‹üõC³OI¦”I„~µ0ÑpFUßÚ³ÚŽUµb(Ÿ%¬Ëo¡ê¸ý`FìBUX{_--ô#uGG‰kA÷ÎÇƒóð ÷ã«wÿ•þ>è½ ¶w½_Þ~<Œ/6?ü1ŒÞ}8í¥ÁÕ[  °WQã:l"ko£:Þ–mà¥Žbç-µe;¦nÑúoã´s÷ÒßÝÚS›Ý`±KÆ–K³7ª»Éd©vO³?´ó ¢=‡X–Ü»Ï‡›ðÃíŽ¹4 %‡:…Ò,†öÄj0üL;Ã‡€—ÙRà…Z ªì@XXÍ·ª…\¹âM¢¬=™4Êž3¨HúÝ1j”Ì[8°HÒÍ7Q­=‘S{àR\‰“Û.ò`í"v/âÍÌt’k\:_• o²WóI%¢ÚÓy©qôFö1‘GJÕù£v)´`}fùv‘j¥ˆî   ™e|ÚÙŸ{BëtN{,±sÈ}KÞŸÌƒ˜9?È>÷ðU Ó!”Ù&lýDK¿\Ù‹DÄòÉrŒ¼wjÿžÊï#:£|R¿[ý\hD¼§ùö Ûs]èŒ­æeŽ`s‹À¶4tŠ<ì¾6:òÉQwä‰~€ÿ²ž¿áyQKÅpümÓfLå'Ù7x†¬¼¨yœf«á+Ûp#%ºÙ%Ä [·@ÿ /¡ôØoY!ûŽ¿ð)Ià¦øÚŽp¿iåXD?‹lZƒµ(ˆG4°Ç›•&«uÐ"¶¬9seN­   UP’Cú¸§Ë˜FÅÞ Vk#\ë÷£“äŸÿìC7î³†ß‰i79ó—S#%Æ Ê––r¬nÊ”Œ",–Ð J5)­ÓViavy"a· ’Ï|â'"öÅY§ÙR„¹ˆ;" 8.Ï,—©ob ,ãÓð“Õº\ãú…•É”ŽíP«zmŽ$*ÈÌábÈîZÑ—}FD4‡Ï äß­Ó4!X¼×"(´š0†úÄÏR€×È‚f…ûOhŒc«u†Ÿ»&o¶ô¿ø,åÐÎq!‚²&£ÂÖkhÏÜ½¬CŸ7=e§_‡Õ*McÑ¢AÌÚ5˜Âl}cqáæ–5¬ÍPÚû¤dó` ¢žQü37öqëâòã#²rHÞì_¼{zBÞœž“w§¿5œx;S•¢˜LÞó ivtà`AŒ(f[zI–IxžLÃßÌ+õ9ÆªsYF=›£;%ý¬«´d   §5¼µ¡a  Má˜Ð!   „ˆg…ý ~Çc;/³Pã-+‹guƒƒ Ï@ë8]lxº7Ì Ç  ë–™”…{–«ÝÈÊTm~¯Éz¹Y‡c˜Îm6­Í­úœcgƒ….øÇÉ.oºh8šØLM8F3¬ÖÑ¨§Ì}F„¾8hÏVÔÏ¥Õ×ÎÊ¥Q„âåÔ¬ˆõ§ýó÷ót]J&¤¡-K%þ.Üá!œÓî“NÌ_u9>·É!í3ù€Î†9$Ï?Ò—·§¾¸PÍ7¨ùP%…¸B¹â@ïÈf”Ev]ˆ   ÈduYYÃ!^gø¾ß©ß%å´=˜fúcšÌ&Ü{“Êö&Ø_‹mj´/¹ø«iáÿÑÍéUi) Ì-LpüÂò‹i´–fÇyk‹­ñéãRZ`RùË¡¤=]éB›g°K­»©·¼t1œå6Æáf³ùÀe5Ó°vfÖtÙ¬&Oókw»¸g6ª3Œõ¹wžöì×‚ª•ûð9æõ×¾#ƒùHô\,s.ÇKÛÚ]æ¶5Ó=(0ö8ÓË/’¦.Ë²_áÖW0w;¼ïnŸû‘×É1lI×Ççwïÿ¼&ºí¦RD]æê© ôóÜ~o8K`UàwüîŸÑüâÄ÷”„ åÿ¹c¼IÂb&žÍðVÝv…POðšcc³dÿ†FÄsB[¼…Û|l3ÚÆß>7f2ÏiD'-ñí‚¥SH‚ÂaÊüÜšÁq!ÓÌ¾,16S¦9I7)‰S®Ìºb”Kç §¯ŠÜ`œðõ†¶ÄgßxYˆ9YÝD.ò¦±Äé\ ÄPÚPó¹¾ˆ±Z—ØBþ†ñ/ä h¿/¾¬+ÀÎ_ ‚kPiÙ±¸7Ä+&ÓžÑ8×½äL÷N¤9—°Ò¼_Ö§–Y‹mÏ0õÙ¶¸1f‹*b7šÈ4ô»güS+x;Añíû(NÕQHy°’¥.ÞœºŒ(ADš|c0|cB!lëN‹,oÖ£‡½ööŸÂ¶Iþ'uÀƒ$a‘g±)sY„j9ñ  ™ê*RùJ FTÄB”Çbe{}šHŒ±>\¾±w,­æ1]ëñà’C¢K˜Ã³ñ^¿&E¯3i_žkXYÏ‘þŽïD:Á?ö’0¿¸¿ìs<1#z(äÝ5«õïÅu1   °YŽVTz`„‘ÍþŠ)hê›uÉÿ_ÌÅ…ô´ÓÃÜÜÆæŽ5Æâ##î\4fí”©ÂDÀ!ªD7o0”E\Ð½MY™L>ÞiáísßgQŽGvÜ”~ö‹£†?<¦    lÀ'[gþßøûm/¾Ýýø×ôìXþöúUxö·íŸÅîéÉka„¸ƒJ  ÿÈx:Úx:zÀvI ›ZÚ\×™µY>ÜóLÄ-žˆ‡ÙMÊ?ÿ›Œÿ‰©r ³v¶!7|ªïKðdý/oþŽ¿;K
```

I also change the permissions of `index.php` but nothing works for me.
Also my `index.php` works, when I write `die('test')` in index.php it displays "test" on the page. I think the problem is in these two lines of code in `index.php`,

```
drupal_bootstrap(DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_FULL);
menu_execute_active_handler();
```

If any one know how to fix this error, Please let me know I'll be very thankful to all of you.
Thanks in Advance...

Comment: OK, so what's in error log? Watchdog table? What happens if you put `die('test')` as a first line of your index.php file?

Comment: If I write die('test') there appears only "test" on the page. error log not showing any error.

Comment: OK, so we know that 1) your index.php is, indeed, executed, and 2) your webserver's configuration is not the cause - because string we know for sure was not misshaped by Drupal displays properly. Please add this to your question.

Comment: I edited my question have you any idea how to fix it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time I have encountered this problem, it has been because I have

- page level caching enabled on admin/config/development/performance
- page compression enabled on admin/config/development/performance
- output compression enabled in .htaccess or httpd.conf (eg, mod_deflate)

The cause is that pages are being compressed twice on the server side, but only decompressed once on the client side.  The solution is to disable page compression in Drupal.

You can add an override to your settings.php

```
$conf['page_compression'] = FALSE;
```

and alter the performance page

```
function MYMODULE_form_system_performance_settings_alter(&$form, $form_state) {
  $form['bandwidth_optimization']['page_compression']['#default_value'] = 0;
  $form['bandwidth_optimization']['page_compression']['#disabled'] = TRUE;
  $form['bandwidth_optimization']['page_compression']['#description'] = t('Handled by Apache.');
}
```